# Heroku worker dyno not showing up even though it is added in Procfile

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js

I am trying to set up Heroku to host my Discord bot. I am sure that I have set up my Procfile correctly, but the worker dyno doesn't show up under Resources. Only the web dyno shows up and that doesn't work as it crashes with error R10 immediately after startup. Can someone help?

Procfile

```
worker: node index.js
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "bot name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "author",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^12.2.0"
  }
}
```

Log

```
2020-07-28T17:03:18.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user 
2020-07-28T17:03:42.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-07-28T16:58:24.618732+00:00 app[api]: Release v20 created by user
2020-07-28T16:58:24.897854+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-07-28T16:58:27.754015+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2020-07-28T16:58:31.218171+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-07-28T16:58:31.218205+00:00 app[web.1]: > bot@0.9.0 start /app
2020-07-28T16:58:31.218206+00:00 app[web.1]: > node index.js
2020-07-28T16:58:31.218206+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-07-28T16:58:32.169174+00:00 app[web.1]: LOG> bot is now online!
2020-07-28T16:58:35.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build started by user 
2020-07-28T16:58:58.755714+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to down
2020-07-28T16:58:58.660155+00:00 app[api]: Deploy 643b70ba by user 
2020-07-28T16:58:58.660155+00:00 app[api]: Release v21 created by user 
2020-07-28T16:58:59.000000+00:00 app[api]: Build succeeded
2020-07-28T16:59:28.079035+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R10 (Boot timeout) -> Web process failed to bind to $PORT within 60 seconds of launch
2020-07-28T16:59:28.102556+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2020-07-28T16:59:28.220163+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
```

[image: Dyno list under Resources tab]

Comment: Is your `Procfile` in the root of your repository? Do you see process types being discovered when you deploy?

Comment: @Chris Yes, Procfile is in the root of my repository. I'm not sure what you mean by "process types being discovered."

Comment: I mean, when you push your code and Heroku builds it there's a bunch of output. Do you see process types being discovered in that output?

Comment: @Chris I updated my post with the logs

Comment: There's barely anything there. Do you have more? Or a previous build output with more detail?

Comment: @Chris Ok, I added the whole log output

Answer (score 0):

I deleted everything and set everything up again and it seems to work now. It's possible that it wasn't working because I didn't have the node_modules folder or because of some other error that happened in the first attempt of setting the bot up.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your heroku app
2. Select Resources menu
3. Turn on the "worker: node index.js" and turn off the "web npm start"