# I am getting the error Error: Cannot find module '/app/index.js' on Heroku

Tags: heroku

My Procfile is:
Worker: index.js
I'm sure that everything is correctly capitalized and I don't know what to do.

Comment: And there is a `index.js` in your projects root directory?

Comment: Yeah, I do have one.

Comment: "I'm sure that everything is correctly capitalized"—then why does your `Procfile` contain `Worker:`, not `worker:`? In any case, your `Procfile` should probably say something more like `worker: node index.js`. Please [edit] your question and show us your entire `Procfile` and your directory structure.

Answer (score 0):

Following the official documentation https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile, you probably should use worker in lowercase :

```
worker: index.js
```

But your error comes from your index.js location.

**EDIT** : I found something in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63124021/heroku-worker-dyno-not-showing-up-even-though-it-is-added-in-procfile), I think you need to use :

```
worker: node index.js
```